# Django queryset filtering not providing expected behavior

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have an app taking inputs from a user on the front end.

The functionality I'm trying to implement should display all titles on the front end that have players <=0, or display NULL values in the database.

```
 player_filter = 'lte'
 if playerinput_high == '0':
        player_kwargs = {
                'player_points__isnull': True,
                'player_points__{}'.format(reviewsign_high): float(playerinput_high)
            }

        stats = stats.filter(**player_kwargs)
```

However, I don't get any results back here. If I remove one parameter, i.e. `'player_reviews__isnull': True`, I do get all titles with reviews less than or equal to 0.

Vice versa, if I remove `'player_reviews__{}'.format(playersign_high): float(playerinput_high)`, I get all stats with NULL stats. But them together, displays 0 results. Any ideas on a solution here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple filters in Django's ORM default to 'AND' when generating SQL. You should look into using the Q object to specify an 'OR' query. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

```
from django.db.models import Q
titles = titles.filter(Q(**review_kwargs, _connector=Q.OR))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm curious, however, where the `_connector` argument is found in any Q object documentation. I understand it's usage, but can't find it online. Could you point me to where I can find Q argument parameters such as `_connector`? Thanks!

Comment: `_connector` is not in the documentation and the variable starts with an underscore indicating it is a private/internal variable and may not be supported in future releases. You could do this another way... import operator, from functools import reduce, titles = titles.filter(reduce(operator.or_, [f"{key}={value}" for key, value in review_kwargs.items()]))